# How can I draw a ruler?

Tags: graphics, drawing

I would like to draw a ruler in the vertical position.

[image]

Ideally, the numbers are horizontal and I can choose begin, end and steps (eg from 1000 to 1200 with steps of 10).

Comment: What would you measure with such a ruler?

Comment: @Luigi: maybe you can expand on this: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/428047

Comment: @bill s: it is an indicator that varies over a linear scale and whose range can change sligthly

Comment: as in `Graphics@GeometricTransformation[{Line[{{0, 0}, {10, 0}}], 
   Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, 10}], 
   Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.5}}], {x, 0, 10, .1}], Thick, 
   Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, 10}], 
   Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.7}}], {x, .5, 9.5}], 
   Table[Text[Style[n, 24], {n, -1.5}], {n, 0, 10}]}, 
  RotationTransform[Pi/2]]`

Comment: I would use `VerticalGauge` for purpose of displaying different values. It is highly customizable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something to point you in a possible direction...

Updated a second time with some modifications from the original.
(I clearly have too much time on my hands today and I fully recognize the silliness of the changes ;-)

```
 Grid[{{
   VerticalGauge[0, {0, 2},
    Background -> LightGray,
    GaugeMarkers -> None,
    ScaleDivisions -> {2, 4},
    TicksStyle -> {{Black, FontSize -> 14}, Gray},
    ScalePadding -> 0.05],
   "   ",
   Column[{Rotate["Ruler ", 270 Degree], 
     Rotate["Ruler +", 90 Degree]}],
   "  ",
   VerticalGauge[0, {0, 7},
    Background -> LightGray,
    GaugeMarkers -> None,
    ScaleDivisions -> {5, 2},
    ScaleOrigin -> {0, {1, 0}},
    TicksStyle -> {{Black, FontSize -> 14}, Gray},
    ScalePadding -> 0.05]}},
 Background -> LightGray, 
 Dividers -> {{3 -> {Gray, Thick}, 4 -> {White, Thick}}}, 
 Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

And...building on @chris's comment:

```
   Manipulate[
     Grid[
      {
       {
        Graphics[
         GeometricTransformation[{
           Line[{{0, 0}, {l, 0}}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, l}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.5}}], {x, 0, l, .1}],
           Thick,
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, l}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.7}}], {x, .5, l - 0.5}],
           Table[Text[Style[n, 24], {n, -1.5}], {n, 0, l}]},
          RotationTransform[90 Degree]],
         ImageSize -> 75
         ],
        " ",
        Column[{Rotate["Ruler ", 270 Degree], 
          Rotate["Ruler +", 90 Degree]}],
        "",
        Graphics[
         GeometricTransformation[{
           Line[{{0, 0}, {l, 0}}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, l}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.5}}], {x, 0, l, .1}],
           Thick,
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -1}}], {x, 0, l}],
           Table[Line[{{x, 0}, {x, -.7}}], {x, .5, l - 0.5}],
           Table[Text[Style[n, 24], {n, -1.5}], {n, 0, l}]},
          RotationTransform[270 Degree]],
         ImageSize -> 75
         ]
        }
       },
      Background -> LightGray, 
      Dividers -> {{3 -> {Gray, Thick}, 4 -> {White, Thick}}}, 
      Alignment -> {{Left, Center, Right}, Automatic}
      ],
     {{l, 10}, 1, 10, 1}
     ]
```

[image]

I like this, but seems someone could simplify it.